# Помогите найти ошибку в реализации Hibernate связи OneToOne

Tags: java-ee, hibernate, jpa

Добрый день! 
Помогите найти ошибку в реализации Hibernate связи OneToOne.

Есть 2 таблицы в PostgreSql

```
CREATE TABLE user_profile
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  first_name character varying(255),
  last_name character varying(255),
  middle_name character varying(255),
  created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  birthday timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT user_profile_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),

);
CREATE TABLE user_account
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  email character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  password character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  login character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  coins integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT user_account_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT user_account_email_key UNIQUE (email),
    CONSTRAINT user_account_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES user_profile (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Так я делаю мапинги (гетеры и сетеры убрал для экономии места) :

```
    @Entity
    public class UserProfile extends AbstractEntity {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @Column
        private String firstName;

        @Column
        private String lastName;

        @Column 
        private String middleName;

        @Column 
        private Date created;

        @Column
        private Date birthday;
}



    @Entity
    public class UserAccount extends AbstractEntity {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @Column
        private String login;

        @Column
        private String password;

        @Column(updatable = true)
        private String email;

        @Column
        private Long coins;

        @MapsId
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE })
        @JoinColumn(updatable = false, name = "id")
        private UserProfile userProfile;
}
```

Тестирование :

```
    @Test
    public void firstTest(){        
       final UserAccount userAccount = createRandomUserAccount();
       final UserProfile userProfile = createRandomUserProfile();
       userService.createNewUser(userAccount, userProfile);
   }




@Override
@Transactional
public void createNewUser(UserAccount userAccount, UserProfile userProfile){
    userAccount.setUserProfile(userProfile);
    accountDao.insertEntity(userAccount);
}

@Override
public Entity insertEntity(final Entity entity){
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    return entity;      
}
```

После выполнения, в БД добавляет только UserProfile, UserAccount остаётся пустым, ошибок никаких нету.

Answer (score 1):

1 - проверьте, что в методе `createRandomUserProfile();` нет persist`а в базу.
Есть подозрение, что у вас конфликт в транзакционных менеджерах - для бизнес логики один, для тестов - другой (если вы, конечно, указываете спринговый Runner).

2 - можно проверить workaround - добавить явно аннотацию `@Rollback`. Хотя при корректной конфигурации оно и так должно быть для тестов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но с ошибкой уже разобрался, забыл обновить вопрос.
Проблема была в том что из конфигурационного файла Spring была удаленна запись - <tx:annotation-driven />. После её добавления всё снова заработало.